# Register SIGTEM handler only for parent process

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals, signal-processing

I have the following program(this is replicated version of a complex program, but pretty much covers my problem statement).

A SIGTERM handler is registered before spanning the new process. I am unable to find a way to restraint the child process from inheriting this handler. I want to do some cleanup activities, but only once for the parent. That said, child process should not have any SIGTERM handlers.

One way might be to overwrite the sigterm handler(after process spawn) and not do anything there. But that seems a redundant code. Can someone help exploring other ways to do this.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import signal
import os
import time
import psutil


def terminateChildProcesses():
    """
    Terminate all child processes
    """
    current = psutil.Process()
    children = current.children(recursive=True)

    for child in children:
        print "Terminating %s: %s" % (child.pid, ''.join(child.cmdline()))
        child.terminate()


def target():
    time.sleep(100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def handle_sigterm(*a):
        print "I am handled: {}".format(os.getpid())

        # terminate child processes
        terminateChildProcesses()
        os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)


    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_sigterm)

    p = Process(target=target)
    p.start()

    target()
```

Comment: As far as I know, the `multiprocessing` library doesn't provide that level of control over what is and isn't inherited by children; you'd have to read the source and subclass or monkeypatch the appropriate class (which is probably `Popen` rather than `Process`) to do it manually.

Comment: As a side note, why are you pulling in `psutil` to kill your children instead of just keeping track of `p` and calling `p.terminate`?

Comment: @abarnert Actually this is a simple replicated version of a bigger application where we might not have track of all child processes. This approach ensures I get all processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I think, you can use `multiprocessing.current_process()` to conditionally register this handler:

```
from multiprocessing import current_process

if current_process().name == 'MainProcess':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_sigterm)
```

Comment: If he's using the fork startmethod (and IIRC, on 2.7 you don't get any choice on Linux, so he is), he has to do this after starting all child processes, or it'll be inherited by the later ones. Which is trivial in his example, but from the comments and the rest of the description, it sounds like it may not be doable at all.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although this might not directly solve my problem, It's still good to know and I can tweak this further to solve my problem. This definitely helps. Child processes have names as 'Process-1', 'Process-2' and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Python 3.7, you can also use `os.register_at_fork()` to restore the previous handler:

```py
import os
import signal

handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_sigterm)
os.register_at_fork(after_in_child=lambda: signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler))
```